# Make your own pagestyle on TOC

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

I have the same page style but I want to change it on the TOC.

I want my document look like the second one, so I would appreciate any idea. I want the TOC only with foot rule and page number on the outer side of pages, without header and headrulewidth.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}                                   
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE]{\textsl{\slshape{\leftmark}}}
\fancyhead[RO]{\textsl{PROYECTO FIN DE MÁSTER}}
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\fancypagestyle{plain}
{%
\fancyhf{}%
%\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}}
\fancyhead[RO]{\textsl{PROYECTO FIN DE MÁSTER}}
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}%
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}% Line at the header invisible
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}% Line at the footer visible
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define `fancy` page style like:

```
\fancyhf{}
%\fancyhead[LE]{\textsl{\slshape{\leftmark}}}
%\fancyhead[RO]{\textsl{PROYECTO FIN DE MÁSTER}}
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
```

Then define an additional page style `mystyle` like this

```
\fancypagestyle{mystyle}
{%
\fancyhead[LE]{\textsl{\slshape{\leftmark}}}
\fancyhead[RO]{\textsl{PROYECTO FIN DE MÁSTER}}
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
}
```

Then use them like

```
\pagestyle{fancy}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\cleardoublepage   %%< ---- be safe
\pagestyle{mystyle}   %% <--- add this here

.
.
.
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhf{}
%\fancyhead[LE]{\textsl{\slshape{\leftmark}}}
%\fancyhead[RO]{\textsl{PROYECTO FIN DE MÁSTER}}
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\fancypagestyle{plain}
{%
\fancyhf{}%
%\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}}
\fancyhead[RO]{}
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}%
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}% Line at the header invisible
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}% Line at the footer visible
}

\fancypagestyle{mystyle}
{%
\fancyhead[LE]{\textsl{\slshape{\leftmark}}}
\fancyhead[RO]{\textsl{PROYECTO FIN DE MÁSTER}}
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\cleardoublepage
\pagestyle{mystyle}   %% <--- add this here
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

If you want head rule for chapter pages, simply replace

```
\fancypagestyle{plain}
{%
\fancyhf{}%
%\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}}
\fancyhead[RO]{}
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}%
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}% Line at the header invisible
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}% Line at the footer visible
}
```

with

```
\makeatletter
\let\ps@plain\ps@fancy
\makeatother
```

Comment: Thank you very much!! But I just don´t understand the last thing you wrote. I want head rule for chapters and I don´t understand what do I have to replace! The other stuff worked perfectly man! Thanks again!

Comment: Sorry, I just understood what you mean!! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @joudaon Glad it helped. :-)